# Auto scheduling posts in Wordpress by specific week days

Tags: php, wordpress, post, scheduling, strtotime

There is a free plugin available for Wordpress called 'Drafts Scheduler' that has an option to schedule an exact number of draft posts a day. However due to the nature of our site we would like to post on a fixed schedule etc. post 5 times every Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday and Sunday. I have been trying to figure out how to make this work but so far with no success.

[Link to the free plugin's source code:](https://github.com/wp-plugins/drafts-scheduler/blob/master/draft-scheduler.php)

I have tried editing this string on line 369:

```
$postsToday = $exactPosts;
$startPosts = date_i18n( 'Y-n-j g:i:s', strtotime( "+1 day", strtotime( $startPosts ) ) );
```

And replace **+1 day** with **next Thursday**,

for example, but all it did was to schedule the posts every Thursday instead of daily. I am not sure how to create a schedule like I wanted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/publish-to-schedule/ or this https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-post-publishing-scheduler/

Comment: I have tried using plugin Publish to schedule before. The problem with it is that it triggers all social auto post plugin even though the posts were only scheduled. Thus the visitors from the social media sites may click to visit a link that's nonexistent and see a 404 page. For the other plugin, I tried using it but find it too restrictive as it forces all types of posts including pending posts to become scheduled automatically according to that fixed time slot. I only needed the draft post to be scheduled as I have another set of posts in pending.

Answer (score 0):

My eyes don't really like it, but this should work.

```
function getNextDayOfWeekCustom($inputdate)
{
    $dow = date('w',strtotime($inputdate));
    switch($dow)
    {
        case 0: //sun
        case 1:
            $result = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next tuesday',strtotime($inputdate)));
        break;
        case 2: //tue
        case 3:
            $result = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next thursday',strtotime($inputdate)));
        break;
        case 4: //thu
        case 5:
            $result = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next saturday',strtotime($inputdate)));
        break;
        case 6: //sat
            $result = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next sunday',strtotime($inputdate)));
        break;
    }

    return date('Y-m-d',strtotime($result));
}
```

Just put $startPosts in it and you'll get next day on schedule.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm sorry but I'm kinda new to php so can you explain more clearly how do I actually put $startPosts in it? And any other codes need to be edited for it too work? Thanks again.

Comment: From your plugin code change the 2nd line to 

` $startPosts = date_i18n( 'Y-n-j g:i:s', getNextDayOfWeekCustom($startPosts) ); `

and if nothing went wrong you should get new postdate from your scenario.
you might have to change date format to suit your plugin as well (that _ 'Y-m-d' _ things in the function).